# How to update datatable in real time of a database external to the laravel 5.5 application

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables, real-time

I have implemented a Laravel 5.5 application for displaying data stored in an external database in a datatable. the external database is powered by an application that monitors the network. I would like to update my datatable in real time and from what I read on the network I understood that:

1. I cannot use Laravel model events because the table is powered by an
   external application and not by Laravel.
2. I cannot launch a Laravel method from a trigger or store procedure
   on MySQL because it is not allowed.

So I ask you who are reading if you can give me an idea on how to get a datatable update in real time or near real time.
I know, I could use the setinterval () function to continuously poll the database. I would like to avoid updating the datatable and would prefer to find a way to use the addRow methods. But I wonder if there is a smarter way to get the real time.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [yajra / laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package with custom queries. You can use [Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) for front end.

```
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/user-data',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
```

For backend,

```
use DB;
use DataTables;

Route::get('/user-data', function() {
    return Datatables::queryBuilder(DB::table('users'))->make(true);
});
```

And you have to install and call  **yajra / laravel-datatables** package but it's real easy five minutes process. Also read [here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter) for more examples.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes I have already created the datatable as you suggested. the problem with polling every 5 minutes is that multiple connected clients don't see the same data at the same time. So the problem remains. I need a solution at least near real time. 5 minutes is not really real time :)

Comment: So you need to refresh datatable after 5 minutes right?. Or do you need to refresh when something added from backend?

Comment: the second one. When something added from backend.

Comment: Think you may need to use websockets for that but unfortunately I don't know a lot about the area :(